# How to get on a Bokeh callback which Object has triggered the callback?

Tags: bokeh

I´m building some bokeh plots functions that, depending on the structured of the supplied data, will have different quantity of Select widgets.

This way, I have a list called 'filters' that contains each Select widget as a list element:

filter = [Select1, Select2, ....]

I´m assingning to each of these function a same callback 'update_dropdown', as code bellow. For the last filter, I finally assign a callback for 'update_plot'.

```
        for f in filters[:-1]:
            f.on_change('value', update_dropdown)

        filters[-1].on_change('value', update_plot)
```

However, for this strategy to be effective I need to get which of the filters has triggered the 'update_dropdown' callback inside the 'update_dropdown' function for it to update the other filters accordingly. IS it possible to accomplish it?

I would expect something like this:

```
def update_dropdown(attr, old, new, FILTER_WHO_TRIGGERED_THE_CALLBACK):
   #doing some stuff here accordingly to the variable FILTER_WHO_TRIGGERED_THE_CALLBACK
```

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it directly - you have to create a separate callback for each filter.

Something like:

```py
def bind_cb_obj(cb_obj, cb):
    def wrapped(attr, old, new):
        cb(cb_obj, attr, old, new)

    return wrapped

filters[-1].on_change('value', bind_cb_obj(filters[-1], update_plot))
```

Comment: Indeed, it even passes the signature check.

Comment: I specifically added tests to cover this usage :)

Comment: Worked very well!!! This partial resource will be a tipping point for me. Thank you very much!